# How to Block clients from a certain IP range, who also have a certain string in referrer?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm getting annoying visits from a certain range of IP's that have a certain string pattern in their referrer.

How can I block such users based on these two conditions together?

for example, any user with IP that starts with `67.*.*.*` and referring url that contains the string `a=foo`?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^67
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?a=foo [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

This will forbid any request with **?a=foo** for all ip addresses that start with **67** .

Comment: thans, what if i want to display them a custom message?

Comment: @Rockyraw To display a custom message, you can use php .

Comment: but PHP is per page, and Htaccess is per domain, I want to block them per my whole domain.

Comment: @Rockyraw you are right php is per page. And yes this is possible to display a custum error msg using htaccess, You can use ErrorDocument like this : **ErrorDocument 403 "Your msg here"** . Texts also go inside double quotes otherwise it is treated as a path.